# Where npm install the packages?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I have some mess with npm.
I'm trying to update npm and other libs with npm but it doesn't update, I tried some solutions but they haven't worked for me.

The following shows the pathnames returned when running; `npm root`, `npm root -g`, and `which npm` via the command-line:

> ```
> $ npm root
> /Users/MYUSER/node_modules
> $ npm root -g
> /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.7.0/lib/node_modules
> $ which npm
> /usr/local/bin/npm
> ```

```
Can you help me understand what is wrong here?
```

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is. Do you have a specific question?  Modules are typically installed within a project's directory.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your confusion. First of all, what is important to know, is that Node is the Software that is running your code. NPM is a package manager, which ships together when installing Node.

As different projects require their specific Node Version, I like using NVM - the Node Version Manager.

The node_modules Directory in your Home Folder exists because you probably have executed the npm install command inside your Home folder. It has created the node_modules Directory and downloaded the packages in there. It is a good practice to keep your HOME Directory as clean as possible, and there is no reason to keep the node_modules Folder there.